# Sind "rauchen von" und "duften von" austauschbar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Im Frühling **raucht** der Park vom Blühen der Blumen, die an den Zweigen der Bäume hängen.
>
> Im Frühling **duftet** der Park vom Blühen der Blumen, die an den Zweigen der Bäume hängen.

Kann man *rauchen von* statt *duften von* schreiben? Oder kann *rauchen von* figurativ verwendet werden?

Comment: Kann man das in Englisch? "Park smokes off the blooming..."? Wenn nicht, dann wie kommst du drauf, das es so sein könnte? Das wäre ein interessanter Teil der Frage...

Comment: Meinst Du wirklich "raucht von", nicht "riecht nach"? Ersteres geht nicht, letzteres schon.

Comment: "rauchen" klingt sehr komisch und ist ungebräuchlich. An Bäumen hängen keine Blumen, die gibt es nur in einer Wiese. Bäume blühen und haben Blüten. Im Englischen kann flower Blume und Blüte sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Keine Bedeutungsgemeinsamkeit

Zwischen *rauchen* (to smoke) und *duften* (to scent) gibt es im Deustchen keine Überlappung in ihrer Bedeutung.

#### Mögliche Verwendung im übertragenen Sinn

In der Poesie, und nur dort, ist aber manches möglich, selbst eine bildliche Übertragung auf die Beschreibung blühender Bäume. Man könnte es vielleicht verwenden, um zu beschreiben, was man an einem sonnigen Frühlingstag sieht, wenn es heftigen Pollenflug gibt und die Bäume zu "rauchen" scheinen:

[image]
<sup>Ingae source: C. Wolf [Forstbotanischer Garten, Göttingen](http://www.uni-goettingen.de/de/biologie-und-oumlkologie/60887.html)</sup>

Das wäre sogar annähernd physikalisch korrekt, da es ja ein Festkörper- und Luftgemisch ist.

Außerhalb einer poetischen Umschreibung würde man aber immer von **Staub** (dust), **Blütenstaub** oder **Pollenflug** reden. Das hat dann aucn nicht im Entferntesten mit dem Duft der Blüten zu tun.

Answer (score 3):

No, 'rauchen' (to fume/smoke) cannot be used in any way to mean 'duften'. (Also, the bloom of a plant is 'die Blüte'.)

> Im Frühling duftet der Park vom Blühen der Blüten, die an den Zweigen
>   der Bäume hängen.

You could use the noun Parfüm (n.) with a little artistic license, e.g.:

> Im Frühling ist der Park vom Parfüm der blühenden Bäume durchdrungen. 
>   
> (In spring, the park is infused with the perfume of the blooming
>   trees.)

(That's what we also call 'blumige Sprache', har har har.)

Comment: Da stellt jemand in einem Deutsch-Forum eine Frage in Deutscher Sprache, die einen Aspekt der Deutschen Sprache zum Inhalt hat und du antwortest in einer Fremdspache. Warum?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Frage wurde auf Englisch gestellt und ist später ins Deutsche übersetzt worden, nachdem ich meine Antwort gepostet hatte.

Answer (score 1):

### Rauch

Rauch ist ein Gemisch aus sehr vielen mikroskopisch kleinen Feststoff- und Flüssigkeits-Partikeln, die ein einem Gas (meist Luft) verteilt sind. Sind die Partikel ausschließlich Flüssigkeits-Tröpfchen, spricht man von Nebel. Die Bezeichnung »Nebel« ist auch dann üblich, wenn die festen Partikel im Rauch Kristalle aus Wasser-Eis sind (z.B in den Wolken am Himmel).

Es handelt sich bei Rauch also um ein Aerosol, das dadurch gekennzeichnet ist, das dessen Bestandteile Phasen sind, die durch Phasengrenzflächen (den Oberflächen der Partikel) voneinander getrennt sind. Diese Phasen haben unterschiedliche physikalische Eigenschaften, insbesondere unterscheiden sich die Partikel und das umgebende Gas in den optischen Eigenschaften (z.B. Brechungsindex). Das führt dazu, dass Rauch - vorausgesetzt er ist nicht all zu sehr verdünnt - immer **sichtbar** ist.

### Wolke

Als Wolke bezeichnet man ein Teilgebiet der Luft, das, im Gegensatz zur umgebenden Luft, von Rauch oder Nebel erfüllt ist.

### Duft

Ein Duft besteht aus Substanzen, die in der Luft gelöst sind (ähnlich wie Salz oder Zucker in Wasser aufgelöst sein kann), und die die Eigenschaft haben, aufgrund ihrer chemischen Beschaffenheit Geruchs-Rezeptoren in den entsprechenden Organen von Tieren zu reizen, insbesondere in den Nasen von Menschen.

Wenn eine Substanz in einer anderen gelöst ist (wie das z.B. bei dem Salz im Meerwasser der Fall ist), gibt es nicht, wie beim Rauch oder Nebel, unterschiedliche Phasen mit unterschiedlichen optischen Eigenschaften. Es gibt eine einzige Phase, in der alle Substanzen gleichmäßig verteilt sind, und die, falls sie durchsichtig ist, klar (also ungetrübt) erscheint.

Einen Duft kann man daher nicht sehen, jedoch - gemäß seiner Definition - immer riechen.

### Duftwolke

Das ist keine Wolke im eigentlichen Sinn, denn eine Duftwolke besteht nicht aus mehreren Phasen, und hat dieselben optischen Eigenschaften wie die umgebende Luft. Mit anderen Worten: Im Gegensatz zu einer *echten* Wolke ist eine Duftwolke unsichtbar. Man kann sie aber riechen, dazu muss man sich aber in ihr befinden.

### rauchen

Das Verb »rauchen« beschreibt den Vorgang der Erzeugung oder Ausstoßung von Rauch. Wenn ein Park raucht, dann brennt er meist, oder er hat gebrannt. Aber auch die intensive gleichzeitige Pollenproduktion bestimmter Pflanzenarten kann als Rauch beobachtet werden, der in Form dünner gelber Schwaden aus den Bäumen entweicht.

### duften

Das Verb »duften« beschreibt den Vorgang der Erzeugung oder Ausstoßung von Duft. Wenn ein Park duftet, bedeutet dies, dass die dort wachsenden Pflanzen Duftmoleküle in die Luft emittieren. Diese Duft-Moleküle sind dann in der Luft gelöst und somit unsichtbar. Man kann den Duft aber wahrnehmen, wenn man diese Duftmolekül-Luft-Mischung einatmet, und die Duftmoleküle an die Rezeptoren in der Nase gelangen.

### FAZIT

**Rauchen** und **duften** bedeuten zwei verschiedene Dinge, die nicht miteinander austauschbar sind. Dennoch sind beide in der Frage genannten Sätze sinnvolle deutsche Sätze, wenn man mal außer Acht lässt, dass zumindest heimische Blumen nicht auf Bäumen wachsen. (Aus diesem Grund habe ich aus jedem Satz zwei Sätze gemacht). Aber diese Sätze haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

> 1. Im Frühling raucht der Park vom Blühen der Blumen.
> 2. Im Frühling raucht der Park von den Blüten die an den Zweigen der Bäume hängen.

Das bedeutet:
1. Im Frühling produzieren die blühenden Blumen so viele Pollen, dass von der Wiese eine sichtbare Pollen-Wolke aufsteigt.
2. Im Frühling produzieren die Blüten der Bäume so viele Pollen, dass von ihnen eine sichtbare Pollen-Wolke aufsteigt.

> 1. Im Frühling duftet der Park vom Blühen der Blumen.
> 2. Im Frühling duftet der Park von den Blüten die an den Zweigen der Bäume hängen.

Das bedeutet:
1. Im Frühling geben die blühenden Blumen so viele Duftstoffe in die Luft ab, dass man sie riechen kann.
2. Im Frühling geben die Blüten der Bäume so viele Duftstoffe in die Luft ab, dass man sie riechen kann.

---

Nur zur Sicherheit (weil ich glaube, dass es hier eine Verwechslung gab):

**Blume**
Das ist meist (nicht immer) eine krautige einjährige Pflanze, die Blüten hervor bringt.

*krautig:* ihr Stängel enthält kein Holz
*einjährig:* sie spriest im Frühjahr aus einem Samen hervor und stirbt im Herbst oder Winter wieder ab.

**Blüte**
Blüten sind die Sexualorgane von Planzen die sich sexuell vermehren. Es sind jene Organe, die die Pollen (entspricht den Spermien bei Tieren) und/oder Samen (entspricht den Eiern bzw Eizellen von Tieren) hervorbringen.

Answer (score -4):

`Duften` beschreibt Gerüche, die in der Regel von Lebewesen abgegeben werden (vgl. *Duftstoffe*). Diese dienen entweder zum Anlocken oder Vertreiben von Lebewesen. `Duft` ist so gesehen eine *Wolke* aus kleinsten, organischen Teilchen, die dafür produziert werden, dass sie von anderen wahrgenommen (gerochen) werden.

`Rauchen` beschreibt das Austreten von Verbrennungsgasen. Wenn etwa Tabak in einer Zigarette verbrennt, *raucht* oder *qualmt* es. Dabei entsteht auch eine Art *Duft*, also Moleküle, die gerochen werden können, aber die Entstehung dieser Moleküle ist eine ganz andere.

Zusammenfassend kann man sagen: Alles, was aktiv Stoffe absondert, die man riechen kann, duftet. Alles, was verbrennt und durch den Verbrennungsvorgang Verbrennungsgase freisetzt, raucht.

Comment: Das würde ich so nicht sagen. _Duft_ beschreibt idR einen als angenehm empfundenen Geruch, aber egal woher er stammt. In der Küche duftet es nach Weihnachtskeksen, ohne dass deswegen Lebewesen im Spiel wären. _Rauch_ entstammt einem Verbrennungsprozess, und kann durchaus auch als angenehm (Räucherstäbchen) empfunden werden, muss es aber nicht.

Comment: "Angenehm" ist sehr subjektiv und absoult relativ. In der Tierwelt gibt es Duftstoffe, die von anderen Tieren als angenehm empfunden werden, die für uns Menschen aber stinken. Duft sollte hier eher wertneutral gesehen werden. Die Duftsoffe, die beim backen entstehen sind aber meist organische Duftstoffe, die durch Hitze gelöst werden. Es sollte jedoch klar sein, worauf meine Antwort abzielt, oder nicht?

Comment: Selbstverständlich ist das subjektiv, und nicht jeder Geruch wird von allen als "Duft" bezeichnet werden. Der Ausdruck als solcher ist aber nicht wertneutral, er gibt im Gegenteil eine Wertung des Sprechers wieder. Insofern ist es keineswegs klar, worauf Deine Antwort abzielt: auf die Herkunft des Geruchs kommt es für die Qualifikation als "Duft" jedenfalls nicht an, wie ich meine. Auch Wikipedia (FWIW) qualifiziert Duft als "harmonischen, angenehmen Geruch". Diese Definition deckt sich mit meinem Verständnis des Wortes.

Comment: Was ist mit geröstetem Knoblauch? Duftet der oder raucht der? Deine Beschreibung, Duft sei hauptsächlich auf Lebewesen zu beziehen ist falsch/scheitert an den Realitäten. Auch für "Duft von Heu" gibt es 5000 Fundstellen und Heu lebt nicht.